# Display the user-disconnected page in NextJs

Tags: next.js

I'm looking for a way to show to user, like WhatsApp web, a page that when connection is poor or user has no internet, says "Your internet connection is down".
How to do this in `Next Js` ?

Answer (score 4):

You have to add this custom hook to your `_app.js` file :

```js
function useNetwork(){
const [isOnline, setNetwork] = useState(window.navigator.onLine);
useEffect(() => {
window.addEventListener("offline", 
        () => setNetwork(window.navigator.onLine)
      );
window.addEventListener("online", 
        () => setNetwork(window.navigator.onLine)
      );
});
return isOnline;
};
```

Add your logic :

```js
const isOnline = useNetwork();

////////////////////////

useEffect(()=>{
  if(!isOnline){
  // show your going offline message here
  }
  
},[isOnline])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can be connected to a network with no internet and it will still return true with this implementation, because the navigator.onLine property only indicates whether the browser has a network connection, not necessarily an internet connection. I think the best way to check the access to internet is to send a request  with axios or fetch api to an existing url at intervals. if the request is ok, then you have internet else no internet. If it takes too long to complete, then you notify you got poor internet.

You can check and update your self by reading the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine